# In 1 Samuel 10:5-6, Music is the ר֣וּחַ יְהֹוָ֔ה Spirit of YHVH?

Tags: prophecy, 1-samuel, spirit

Harmonious vibrations (Music) from the drum, flute & harp passed over שָׁאוּל֙ Shaul in 1 שְׁמוּאֵ֔ל Shmuel 10:5-6.

> [1 שְׁמוּאֵ֔ל Shmuel 10:5]
> "Afterwards, you shall come to the hill of God, where there are Philistine officers, and it will be, that when you come there to the city, you will meet a band of prophets descending from the high place, and before them will be a psaltery and a drum, and a flute and a harp, and they will prophesy." ( אַ֣חַר כֵּ֗ן תָּבוֹא֙ גִּבְעַ֣ת הָאֱלֹהִ֔ים אֲשֶׁר־שָׁ֖ם נְצִבֵ֣י פְלִשְׁתִּ֑ים וִיהִי֩ כְבֹאֲךָ֨ שָׁ֜ם הָעִ֗יר וּפָגַעְתָּ֞ חֶ֚בֶל נְבִאִים֙ יֹרְדִ֣ים מֵֽהַבָּמָ֔ה וְלִפְנֵיהֶ֞ם נֵ֚בֶל וְתֹף֙ וְחָלִ֣יל וְכִנּ֔וֹר וְהֵ֖מָּה מִֽתְנַבְּאִֽים )

> [1 שְׁמוּאֵ֔ל Shmuel 10:6]
> "And the Spirit of YHVH will pass over you, and you will prophesy with them, and you will be turned into another man." ( וְצָלְחָ֚ה עָלֶ֙יךָ֙ ר֣וּחַ יְהֹוָ֔ה וְהִתְנַבִּ֖יתָ עִמָּ֑ם וְנֶהְפַּכְתָּ֖ לְאִ֥ישׁ אַחֵֽר )

- **Is Music the Spirit of YHVH that helps fill us with God's Word?**

Answer (score 1):

Music is not the Spirit of YHVH, it is a vessel to conduct the message of the Spirit of YHVH. Passionate speeches in Bible often expressed in poetic format, and certainly this format can be sung and pass on from one generation to next generation. It is effective and essential particular in those day lack of written materials.

God gave His words often in poetic songs. Even the evil prophet Balaam who was hired by the King of Moab to curse the Israelite, whenever he cursed, his words turned into a song of blessing to the Israelite (Numbers 23:7-10, 23:18-24, 24:3-9, 24:15-19). Both Moses and Isaiah sang "The LORD is my strength and song" (Exodus 15:2, Isiah 12:2 KJV).

The title question is an episode during which Samuel was sent to anoint Saul as King. To established his authority, Samuel prophesized a few incidents that Saul was going to meet. Although the Spirit of God could come upon Saul without his awareness, if this were the case, the person would attribute the strength to their own abilities rather than recognizing it as a grace from God.

Answer (score 0):

The Spirit of YHVH, by definition, is a spiritual (verticle) reality. Music is generated by sound waves which we can physically detect with our ears. It belongs to the horizontal reality.

Would harmonious vibrations of instruments/voices be the **actual** Spirit of YHVH?

No, they could accompany the Spirit but cannot be the actual Spirit Himself.
A similar event happened when Jesus was born in Bethlehem, Luke 2:

> 13 Suddenly a great company of the **heavenly** host appeared with the **angel**, praising God and saying,

A company of angelic beings (spirits) appeared and they sang:

> 14 “Glory to God in the highest heaven,
> and on earth peace to those on whom his favor rests.”

In this case, angelic spirits generated harmonious vibrations of voices but the vibrations themselves were not the angels.

Comment: Messengers "Angels" are not considered the Ruach YHVH. - The question regards the Spirit that fills them with God's Word. - Is Music the Spirit of YHVH that helps fill us with God's Word?

Comment: I see. I'll think about it more :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my 2nd attempted answer after the question has been edited.

It is important to distinguish between the person of the Holy Spirit from the functions of the Holy Spirit. I use the pronounce "he" referring to the person and "it" referring to a function. Sometimes, the Holy Spirit is referred to as fragmentable unction (physical anointing) which I consider also as a function of the Holy Spirit.

1 Samuel 10:

> 5 “After that you will go to Gibeah of God, where there is a Philistine outpost. As you approach the town, you will meet a procession of **prophets** coming down from the high place with **lyres, timbrels, pipes and harps** being played before them, and they will be **prophesying**.

There was an association of prophets and prophesying with musical instruments.

> 6 The Spirit of the Lord will **come** powerfully upon you, and you will **prophesy** with them; and you will be changed into a different person.

I consider this as a function of the Holy Spirit. Saul was anointed by an unction.

OP: Harmonious vibrations (Music) from the drum, flute & harp passed over שָׁאוּל֙ Shaul in 1 שְׁמוּאֵ֔ל Shmuel 10:5-6.

I'd interpret this as the unction of the Spirit passed over Saul while he was submerged in the music.

Is Music the Spirit of YHVH that helps fill us with God's Word?

Yes, in the unction/anointing sense, it can be as described also in Luke 2:12-13 where shepherds saw the angels and heard their musical voices announcing the birth of Christ.
The shepherds were submerged in the angelic sounds and words of God.

Answer (score -1):

The value of music comes from the fact that in it's physics; frequencies and harmonics, consonances, dissonances, intervals, chords and rhythmns etc, music encapsulates the deepest cosmic principles of energy. Music has long been considered to be able to represent in it's essential nature and manifestations the 'pulse-beat of the Universe'. Thus it is the nature of 'sacred music' to align itself with the cosmos and express it's laws etc. As an example the Octave is central in music as it is in reality; the physics of light, sound, and matter (chemical elements) all manifest according to the laws of the octave. So, the octave, or Law  of Seven as George Gurdjieff termed it, is as much a part of the universe's mathematics or geometries as Pi, or Phi are, or even Alpha, the Fine Structure Constant can be said to be. It is curious that Jesus said of himself;

"I am the Alpha and Omega" (Revelation 22.13)

In modern physics Alpha is the letter used for the Fine Structure Constant, which is a fundamental physical constant which 'quantifies the strength of the electromagnetic interaction between elementary charged particles' (as Wikipedia puts it); this means all particles within atoms such as electrons and protons, and the forces which bind them together. In other words, as a part of the framework of the universe, even within the forcs of light. The Omega may represent the circle or sphere of the heavens, or indeed the structure of all atoms in which electrons orbit the proton constituting the bulk of the atom's mass at the centre. Much like the Sun contains 99% of the solar system's mass...
Another way of describing the relationship between matter and energy comes from the Creation, when the Spirit, or Word, or Breath of God which 'hovered over the void' issued forth to create the material universe;

"In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the
face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters"
(Genesis 1.1-2)

The word 'moved' - 'merachephet', from the verb 'rachaph',  - can be interpreted or translated as 'hovered above', or 'vibrated' thus linking it with the vibrational rates of the elements of the material universe; hydrogen, helium and so on. The elements can be seen as particles or expressions of the Absolute which evolved one after the other, representing different levels of materiality. The Qaballah has a similar model of the creation of the levels of reality from the highest sphere of energy (Kether) downwards. Therefore writers such as Gordon Strachan, author of the excellent book on Chartres cathedral, maintain the word 'merachephet' can be translated as 'resonated', meaning on a fundamental level which is akin to the pulse of the universe, something which underpins material reality; the 'cosmic dance'. Music is the opposite of entropy, and chaos, containing harmony, information and the creative forces which can express the nature of the cosmos. The excellent works of Ernest McClain (The Myth of Invariance), and Gordon Strachan (The Bible's Hidden Cosmology, p91) are concerned with examining of the links between the physics of vibration, the universe, music, number and the Bible.

The Eastern word AUM represents this sense of the vibrational harmonic of God's Word throughout the universe, and connects with the rhythmn's of breath across all levels of reality. The Hindu religion has a saying 'Life is Breath', which defines every living being by the rate of it's breathing. God as the cosmos can be conceptualised as breathing in and out, on a time-scale that is appropriate to the Absolute, ie the level of 'All Galaxies'. In the Bhagavad-Gita and other Indian religious texts this is called 'the Great Breath of Brahma' which is the outwards evolution of worlds and galaxies and then the inward phase in an eternal cycle...(Bhagavad-Gita 8.17-18).

On the day of the Temple's consecration (1Kings 8.10) the use of 288 musicians (a cosmic number with regard to frequency and sacred geometry) within the geometric cubic space of the Holy-of-Holies (1Kings 6.20) caused a thick cloud of smoke to materialize; the 'glory of the Lord' as the Bible calls it. (1Kings 8.10-66, and 2Chronicles 6.1-42).

Many other examples represent the (virtually always) sacred nature of music within the Bible...for example when Saul is rejected by YHVH (1Samuel 16.14) and becomes troubled thereafter, his servants look for someone talented in music to soothe and assuage him; the youth David is the person chosen (1Samuel 16.15-19);

16.Let our Lord now command thy servants, which are before thee, to seek out a man, who is a cunning player on a harp: and it shall come to pass, when the evil spirit from God is upon thee, that he shall play with his hand, and thou shalt be well.
18.Then answered one of the servants, and said, Behold, I have seen a son of Jesse the Bethlehemite, that is cunning in playing, and a mighty valiant man, and a man of war, and a comely person, and the Lord is with him.

The cosmological and mathematical basis of music and the octave formed the foundation of the works of Pythagoras, circa 570-495Bce who studied the frequencies/ vibrations of a musical instrument's string when its length was changed by a definite numerical ratio. The philosophy of Pythagoras was thus centred upon the 'Music of the Spheres' - the innate harmonies of the stars and planets in their ordered courses...
As the first chapter of Genesis 1.14 states;

"let (the stars) be for signs and for seasons and for days and for years"...

It is possible to relate Pythagorean theories of energies resonating through all types of matter to modern physics' Quantum 'string theory', thus uniting old and new.